# VBA for isblank to enter values into form

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, trim, nonblank

I am new to scripting VBA from scratch. I have been using formulas to complete the task, but it is requested that I use a VBA to eliminate the excess spacing needed for my formulas to work properly. I have multiple worksheets that I want to the data from to populate my form(s). If column `A` represents the selection of the item by entering the quantity or `no charge(NC)`. example of my worksheet is:

[image]

I have the selected data in if `isblank = false` formulas that combines the selected line into one string for the order form. Then I use the left, right, and mid formulas to separate the string into the columns needed for my check list form.
What I want to do is eliminate using the one text string, and use the if `isblank = false` to populate my check list form.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to receive the most effective help here. As your quesiton is written you will likely receive little help and have the question closed. You'll need examples of your problem and the code you have already tried.

Comment: @newguy i was being sarcastic. not having a great day.

Comment: @Jaumzera thank you for taking time to assist me. appreciate it.